# How easy is to relocate a plumbing vent pipe fixed verically on an outside wall to a different wall

Tags: pipe, vent

I recently had a loft extension with bathroom in it. My builders have installed the vent pipe on the wall outside the extension on the wall shared with one of my neighbours.

Now my neighbours are claiming that the pipe is trespassing their air space and want it moved away.

The vent pipe is also connected to the soil pipe from the outside (the soil pipe is on another outside wall so the connection from the vent to the soil pipe goes round the corner).

My question is: is it possible to relocate the vent pipe and the pipe connection to the soil pipe.

Assuming that this is possible, is this an easy and straight forward job? What is involved in doing this?

Comment: I think adding a rough diagram would help in making your question answerable.

Comment: Or some pictures would go a long way too.